# Embeding Flash - movie and src parameter

Tags: flash, embedding

In this object element there is a child element called param[@name = 'movie']

```
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="324" data="flashlet.swf" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
        <param name="movie" value="flashlet.swf">
        <param name="swliveconnect" value="true">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="FlashVars" value="id=120231">
    </object>
```

I have seen other object element examples which has param[@name = 'src'] instead of name=movie.

So, does anyone here knows the difference between the two?

Thanks for answers,

regards bob

Answer (score 0):

if you check [HTML  tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp) in W3Schools , you will find the syntax you provided is the one supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

This kind of set is used for w3c compliant.
The use of param[@name='src'] is given by Adobe(tm) DreamWeaver when you insert flash-embed content.
The use of the object given by Adobe(tm) DreamWeaver has some bad things: It isn't w3c compliant, and the one you've posted is w3c compliant.
Unfortunately, if you're using the w3c compliant tag, you should follow the flash satay technique from http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay to work on IE

Comment: Yes the code above is missing closing of the param tag /, my mistake :)
But both param/@name=src and param/@name=movie validates as XHTML strict.

Answer (score 0):

While the difference has been listed already in the answers to this question, in general I would tend not to worry about the differences. I say this only because I recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

This will take care of your `object` tag for you.  As well it handles things like Flash Player version detection, player upgrades/downloads, and displaying alternative content if the user does not have/want Flash.

It's very easy to use, here is a simple sample:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("myFlashContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9", "expressInstall.swf", null, null, null, alertStatus);
```